# Dropdownlist conditional postback?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list whose auto postback is set to true and selectedindexchanged event is used for some logic. But the condition is when other data is changed on the page i need to warn user about the changes by showing a confirmation dialogue. I am using javascript to do this but the problem is post back is not happening even when the function returns true. I have no idea whats wrong. Can some body help regarding this.

```
function ValidateDataChange() {
        var isDataChanged = $('#<%=hdnDataIsChanged.ClientID %>').val();
        if (isDataChanged == "True") {
            alert(isDataChanged);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHierarchy" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true"
                        onchange="return ValidateDataChange();" Enabled="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlHierarchy_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="--Select Hierarchy--"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDataIsChanged" runat="server" />


 protected void ddlHierarchy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //mycode
    }
```

Comment: why u use Enabled="false" here? is it hit on the alert?

Comment: it will be enabled when a search is performed on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

selectedIndexChanged is bound to the onchange event of your DDL client-side.

By writing

```
onchange="return ValidateDataChange();"
```

you are in fact doing :

```
onchange="return ValidateDataChange(); __doPostBack(this.id,'');"
```

Because of the return, `__doPostBack` will never be hit.

You should try :

```
onchange="if(!ValidateDataChange()) return false;"
```